# Replace specific characters (a list of them) in a string without removing blanks

Tags: string, sas

I'm trying to work with manually inserted strings in SAS and I need to remove specific special characters (maybe by inserting a list of them) without removing blank spaces between words.

I've found a possible solution with a combination of `compbl` and `transtrn` to remove special characters and substitute them with blanks, reduced to one by `compbl` but this requires multiple steps.

I'm wondering if there is a function that allows me to do this in a single step. I've tried with the compress function (with the 'k' modifier to keep only letters and digits) but it removes blanks between words.

I'd like to go from a string like this one:

`O'()n?e /, ^P.iece`

To:

`One Piece`

With a single blank between the two words.

If someone can help me it would be awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the next tags for `compress` function:

> k -- **K**eep chars instead replace it
>
> a -- **A**lphabetic chars
>
> s -- **S**pace characters
>
> d -- **D**igits

And after it, use function `COMPBL`.

Code:

```
data have;
   value="O'()n?e /, ^P.iece";
run;

data want;
   set have;
   value_want=COMPBL((compress(value,,"kasd"));
run;
```

So:

```
+--------------------+------------+
|       value        | value_want |
+--------------------+------------+
| O'()n?e /, ^P.iece | One Piece  |
+--------------------+------------+
```

Comment: Awesome! It works perfect; thank you very much for the help, I didn't know I could put more modifiers all together.

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex and `prxchage`.

```
data have;
   value="O'()n?e /, ^P.iece";
run;

data want;
   set have;
   value_want=value_want=prxchange("s/\s\s+/ /",-1,prxchange("s/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]*//",-1,value));
run;
```

Result:

```
+--------------------+------------+
| value              | value_want |
+--------------------+------------+
| O'()n?e /, ^P.iece | One Piece  |
+--------------------+------------+
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, I've never used Regular Expressions before but your solution make me want to start to study them immediately, so fascinating!